# Flutter: How to Access Data & NotifyListeners Outside a Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, stream-builder

I have a list of items and a stream within a class. The stream triggers a future where then notifylisteners is called to update the list of items. It works, but it only shows updates within the stream. How do I notifylistners outside the stream as well?

Where, if I were to call Provider.of(context).items it won't return as empty.

Here is the following code structure.

```
class Mans with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Man> _items = [];

  List<Man> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

Stream<List<Man>> stream;
  bool hasMore;
  bool _isLoading;
  List<Man> _data;
  StreamController<List<Man>> _controller;

  Mans({page = 1}) {
    _data = List<Man>();
    _controller = StreamController<List<Man>>.broadcast();
    _isLoading = false;

    // Test if list prints #1
    items.forEach((list) {
      print("nono: ${list.id}");
    });

    stream = _controller.stream.map((List<Man> mansData) {
    // Test if list prints #2
    items.forEach((list) {
      print("nono: ${list.id}");
    });

      return mansData;
    });
    // Test if list prints #3
    items.forEach((list) {
      print("nono2: ${list.id}");
    });

    hasMore = true;

    refresh();
  }

Future<void> refresh() {
    return loadMore(
      page: 1,
      clearCachedData: true,
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadMore(
      {bool clearCachedData = false,
      page = 1}) async {
    if (clearCachedData) {
      _data = List<Man>();
      hasMore = true;
    }
    if (_isLoading || !hasMore) {
      return Future.value();
    }
    _isLoading = true;
    return await fetchAndSetMans(page)
        .then((mansData) {
      _isLoading = false;
      _data.addAll(mansData);
      hasMore = (mansData.isNotEmpty);
      _controller.add(_data);
    });
  }
Future<List<Man>> fetchAndSetMans(page) async {
    var cookie = '';
    try {
      print('Called_API_Mans');

      var response = await SiteApi(serverConfig["url"]).getAsync("api_link?view_id=$page");

      List<Man> list = [];

      for (var item in response) {
    //This just adds an instance of Man to the list from a Model not added to this Stack Question. It works.
        list.add(Man.fromJson(item));
      }

      _items = list;

      notifyListeners();

      return _items;
    } catch (error) {
       return [];
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I placed three different instances where I can print the items after notifyListeners() is called in the Future 'fetchAndSetMans'.

Unfortunately, only in the one where the comment says "Test if list prints #2" does it show that the list has been updated. Basically, within the stream data.

#1 and #3 are empty.

So, anything outside of the stream, notifyListeners() doesn't update the items list.

I wish to know how I can update the value outside the stream when the future is called.

So, if I call a Provider.... like, Provider.of(context).items... I can actually get results.

Thanks, I'd appreciate any help.